# Error installing cassandra_ecto - Elixer phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

While installing cassandra_ecto and starting the server, facing some error as

```
** (Mix) Could not start application cqerl: could not find application file: cqerl.app
```

could not able to proceed after it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used the cassandra_ecto library, but this error usually means that a dependency is missing from your application. Do you have the `cqerl` library listed in your `deps` function?

```
def deps do
  [
    {:cqerl, github: "matehat/cqerl", tag: "v1.0.4"},
    ...
  ]
end
```

If so, have you also added it to your list applications that should be started?

```
def application do
  [applications: [:cqerl, ...]]
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used 1.0.2 version, now i changed the version to 1.0.4. Now that issue was fixed, but created new issue as ` Could not start application cas: Cas.start(:normal, []) '

Comment: I am guessing it's a similar issue, try adding `:cas` to your applications list as you did with `:cqerl`